# How to extend a mountable engine's model inside another mountable engine with development environment reloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

Using Rails 3.2.2 and Ruby 1.9.2.

I have a rails mountable engine `EngineA` that declares a `User` class inheriting form `ActiveRecord::Base`.  I have another engine `EngineB` that wants to inject functionality into `EngineA::User`.  Right now what I have done is shown below:

**Method 1:**

```
#EngineA app/models/engine_a/user.rb
module EngineA
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :avatar
    has_many :somethings
  end
end

#EngineB lib/engine_b/user.rb
module EngineB
  module User
    def self.extended obj
      obj.class_eval do
        has_many :something_elses
      end
    end
  end
end

EngineA::User.extend EngineB::User
```

This gives me an `uninitialized constant EngineA::User` error.  Even when I require that specific file I run into the problem of `EngineA` needing paperclip so that `has_attached_file` is understood.  That road ended when I realized I would have to know and require the dependencies for `EngineA` inside `EngineB`.

**Method 2:**

I used the same code as before except I removed the last line `EngineA::User.extend EngineB::User` from the `EngineB` user.rb file.  I then moved that call to an initializer inside `EngineB`.

```
#EngineB config/initializers/my_mixin.rb
EngineA::User.extend EngineB::User
```

**This worked perfectly!!!**  Except in development mode when I would change code and the models would refresh.  The only thing that was refreshed was the `EngineA::User` and not the mixin that I had put as an initializer.  So once I changed code, I lost all of my extended functionality.

I'm not even positive this is the most 'efficient' way to do this... any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [configuration documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html), you can use an `ActionDispatch` callback to load items.  These callbacks will run when at every request if `cache_classes` is set to false, like in development mode.

Inside of your `EngineB.rb` file, you might try something like this:

```
if Rails.env.development?
    ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do
        load "#{File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))}/../config/initializers/my_mixin.rb"
    end
end
```