# Re-open an ActiveRecord model that's provided by a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems, metaprogramming

I'm trying to extend an ActiveRecord model (`Vote`) that a gem (https://github.com/peteonrails/vote_fu) provides to my application. (I.e., there is no `vote.rb` in `app/models`)

My first approach was to create a file called `lib/extend_vote.rb` that contains the code:

```
Vote.class_eval do
  after_create :create_activity_stream_event
  has_one :activity_stream_event

  def create_activity_stream_event
    # something..
  end
end
```

This works when the first vote is created, but when I try to create each subsequent vote I get the error `TypeError (can't dup NilClass)`.

I think this error is caused by the fact that the `Vote` class is reloaded automatically after every request, but the code in `lib/extend_vote.rb` is loaded only once when  the server starts and this causes the `has_one :activity_stream_event` association to behave weirdly. (Also, the problem goes away if I set `config.cache_classes = true` in `development.rb`)

To solve this problem, I tried to make the vote extensions reload on every request by adding a `to_prepare` block to my `development.rb`:

```
config.to_prepare do
  load 'extend_vote.rb'
end
```

This solves the `(can't dup NilClass)` problem, but now whenever I create a new vote, the `create_activity_stream_event` callback gets called an additional time. I.e., the first vote calls it once, the second calls it twice, etc, etc. So it seems like the `to_prepare` block is reloading the extension TOO aggressively and adding duplicate callbacks.

What's the best way to add methods and callbacks to this `Vote` model?

Comment: Does it work if you just use `class Vote` instead of `Vote.class_eval`? One thing you could do as well is edit the code in the gem itself, and just use your modified version.

Comment: `class Vote` behaves the same as `Vote.class_eval` – neither work. I guess I could modify the gem, but I really really don't want to lol. What a mess!

Comment: Why do you think than the Vote class is reloaded? In the resposity, the class is in the lib directory so it's the same than you...

Answer (score 6):

[UPDATE: should be the right solution to prevent the module being include several times in the same class]

I believe you can use [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) to prevent the module being include several times which result by callback called several time.
See the example below :

```
module VotePatch
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_create :create_activity_stream_event
    has_one :activity_stream_event
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def create_activity_stream_event
      #your code here
    end  
  end

end

Vote.send(:include, VotePatch)
```

Comment: updated my answer, I believe ActiveSupport::Concern will fix your problem

Answer (score 4):

A word of caution: this is a very old gem (last commit is 3 years old) and by the looks of it won't work with rails 3.x as is. In Rails 3.x engines makes this sort of stuff way easier.

As I understand it the problem in the first case is not that the vote model gets reloaded (it shouldn't) but that the `activity_stream_event` model is reloaded. Because the vote model isn't reloaded the association is left hanging onto the version of the `activity_stream_event` class from before the reload. Since rails guts out classes before they get reloaded, this causes problems.

With this in mine, try this hack:

```
#in config/initializers/abstract_vote.rb
AbstractVote = Vote
AbstractVote.abstract_class = true
Object.send :remove_const, :Vote

#in app/models/vote.rb

class Vote < AbstractVote
  after_create :create_activity_stream_event
  has_one :activity_stream_event

  def create_activity_stream_event
  end
end
```

What this does is allow you to have your own Vote class that inherits from the one in the gem.

But again, I urge you to find something more up to date or roll your own (the gem is only ~250 lines of ruby)

Answer (score 2):

I'd try what agmcleod suggested in the comments but instead of putting it in lib, put it in **config/initializers/vote.rb**:

```
 class Vote
   after_create :create_activity_stream_event
   has_one :activity_stream_event

   def create_activity_stream_event
   # something..
   end
 end
```

Of course, you could fork the gem, make your modifications and link to your forked version in your Gemfile (that's my preference).

Comment: why `config/initializers` instead of `lib`? I assume I need to keep the `load` statement in the `to_prepare` block?

Comment: nope shouldn't need that load statement since the items in the initializer files are loaded once at startup for all environments.

Comment: This doesn't work – if I leave the `load` in the `to_prepare` block, I get the same error I got when the file was in `lib`. If I REMOVE the `load`, then I get the `(can't dup NilClass)` error

Comment: Seriously did you actually down vote me for that suggestion?!! Wow. Sorry for the attempt to help but this works for me just fine with EVERY gem I've ever monkey patched like this. You might also try the other suggestion of forking the gem - but not if you're just going to penalize me for it...geesh.

Answer (score 1):

Adrien Coquio has the right idea with `ActiveSupport::Concerns`, which are [the Rails way](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns) to extend models. His code will work, and you should use it.

However this will not work all the time in development because when Rails reloads your classes when a file changes, it will not re-evaulate the `#send` line. The only solution I could find was attaching to an `ActionDispatch` callback in production to ensure the file is re-required after every page load:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do
    require_dependency "../../lib/vote_fu_extensions"
  end
end
```

In production, or if you set `cache_classes` to true in your config, you won't need to do this.

- [A source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772468/how-to-extend-a-mountable-engines-model-inside-another-mountable-engine-with-de)
- [RoR guides about configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)
- [This suggests it has been deprecated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Callbacks/to_prepare/class) and you should use `ActionDispatch::Reloader` callbacks instead? Haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

could you try something like this :

```
class Vote
    after_create :create_activity_stream_event
    has_one :activity_stream_event

    def create_activity_stream_event
        # something..
    end
end
```

I think than it will add your function and call functions "after_create" and "has_hone".

Comment: Sorry, I don't seen the agmcleod's comment. It's probably the same think... It should work but it doesn't.

Comment: heh, at least you didn't get a down vote like I did...and our suggestions were, well, the same! lol

Comment: This is may be because you say to put it in a initializer. Or, may be, I say it after you.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be due to the fact that you are monkey patching the class. When rails tries to reload the constants 
it is not considering your file.

Try to use module technique as given below.

Add a file called `lib/vote_fu_extension.rb`

```
module VoteFuExtension
  def self.included(base)
    base.has_one :activity_stream_event
    base.after_create :create_activity_stream_event
  end
  def create_activity_stream_event
    # something..
  end  
end
Vote.send(:include, VoteFuExtension)
```

Add an initializer called `config/initializers/vote_fu.rb`

```
require "vote_fu_extension"
```

**Note**

If you want to add class methods to the `Vote` model refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328984/rails-extending-activerecordbase/2329394#2329394).

Shameless plug: My [fork](https://github.com/kandadaboggu/vote_fu) of the `vote_fu` gem has some new features and enhancements.