# User Model Patch works only for a few requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, ruby-on-rails-plugins, redmine, redmine-plugins

I needed the patch for my Redmine plugin in order to add a new 'has_many' relation for User Model. It works for a while after I start the rails server in dev mode however strange enough stops working after few requests.

Here is my patch:

```
require_dependency 'project'
require_dependency 'principal'
require_dependency 'user'

module UserPatch
  def self.included(base) 
    base.extend(ClassMethods)

    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)

    # Same as typing in the class 
    base.class_eval do
      unloadable # Send unloadable so it will not be unloaded in development
      has_many :favourites

    end

  end

  module ClassMethods

  end

  module InstanceMethods
  end

end

User.send(:include, UserPatch)
```

Here is the Error log:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `favourites' for #<User:0x007f99cbc3d478>):
  activemodel (3.2.3) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:148:in `method_missing'
  plugins/redmine_asset_tracker/app/controllers/asset_types_controller.rb:20:in `index'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__2420136461919276817__process_action__3214240126008154381__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  rack-openid (1.3.1) lib/rack/openid.rb:98:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:467:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4577554638097020546__call__1559518111822758715__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/myth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/myth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/myth/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Could you please try it in production environment (`rails s -e production`) and see if you got the same behavior ? If not, the error you saw is probably a result of the auto-reloading in development.

Comment: It seems to be working fine. How do I make it work for my development mode as well? This happens very frequently and is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
module UserPatch
  def self.included(base) 
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
    base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
    # Note the change below
    base.unloadable 
    base.has_many :favourites
  end

  module ClassMethods    
  end

  module InstanceMethods
  end

end
```

You can run the class methods on the class in the `included` section.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your models get reloaded but that this extension doesn't? What would happen if you included the extension from the model itself?

Comment: Are you hinting on updating the model code? I am building a plugin,cannot update the model directly.

Comment: My bad, missed that. You could try running in production mode (like @AdrienCoquio also suggests), that will give you the same answer.

Comment: It works in production mode. How do I fix it in dev mode as well? It is quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

As this is only not working in development environment, it is an issue with the class reloading in development.

Adding a config in your `config/environments/development.rb` :

```
config.to_prepare do
  load 'user_patch.rb'
end
```

Should ensure it is reloaded for each request.

With this, you may be surprised that the module may be include several times in User, to fix it, you may use [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

There are 2 questions which may help you :

- [Re-open an ActiveRecord model that's provided by a gem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10761059/793002)
- [Rails extending ActiveRecord::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2328984/793002)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Passenger or not? If you're using passenger, it might be difficult to guarantee when to load it, how far the loaded object is used, etc.

I had similar issue [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003576/passenger-migrations-and-class-constants-loaded-from-table) which I can't get answer. I also did global variable initialization in similar way and it seems like not guaranteed to work.

I solved my issue by not depend on when/how many times out-of-a-method statement execution ran.

Part of the issue can be avoided by the answers given already, but as far as you're using Passenger, this is not easy, as far as I tried.